# Get element from math.matrix in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mathjs

I'm using the matrix element from the [math.js](https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html) library.

I create a matrix:

```
 let eye = math.matrix([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
    ]);
```

But when I try to access an element of the matrix, it is always undefined.

```
console.log(eye[0][0]) -> undefined 
console.log(eye[0])  -> undefined
```

Any suggestions? I have read through the documentation for the math.js library and I see nothing about how to access an individual element.

And I do need to use this library, as I am doing matrix-based operations (matrix multiplication).

Comment: console.log(eye) first.. then depending on that i'd probably tell you to duplicate the matrix object eye.. just `console.log(eye)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print out `eye`, you get the following object.

```json
{
  _mathjs: "DenseMatrix",
  _data: [
    [ 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 1, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1 ]
  ],
  _size: [ 3, 3 ]
}
```

---

But that is just the internal structure used to hold information about the matrix, you need to call helper methods as seen in the docs.

- https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/subset.html
- https://mathjs.org/examples/matrices.js.html

If you want to access the data, you can always interrogate the internal `matrix` data directly. This is a bad idea, because the fields are all treated as private; internal fields (start with an underscore).

```js
const __print = (x) => console.log(JSON.stringify(x));

let eye = math.matrix([
  [1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1]
]);
   
__print(eye._data[0][0]); // 1

__print(eye._data[0]);    // [1, 0, 0]
__print(eye._data[1]);    // [0, 1, 0]
__print(eye._data[2]);    // [0, 0, 1]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/8.1.1/math.js"></script>
```

It is recommended that you use the helper methods which are available in the library.

**Note:** After fine-tuning my response, I found a similar method of retrieving a row in the [Issue #230](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/issues/230#issuecomment-62515661) on GitHub.

You need to figure out the number of columns in the matrix. After that, you can grab a subset starting at the desired row index with a range of 0 to the number of columns in the row. The result must then be flattened.

```js
const __print = (x) => console.log(JSON.stringify(x));

let eye = math.matrix([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]);

const __row = (m, r) =>
  (([ rows, cols ]) => math.flatten(math.subset(m,
    math.index(r, math.range(0, cols))).valueOf()))
  (m.size());
  
const __col = (m, c) =>
  (([ rows, cols ]) => math.flatten(math.subset(m,
    math.index(math.range(0, rows), c)).valueOf()))
  (m.size());
  
const __cell = (m, r, c) =>
  math.subset(m, math.index(r, c));

__print(__cell(eye, 0, 0)); // 1

__print(__row(eye, 0));     // [1, 2, 3]
__print(__row(eye, 1));     // [4, 5, 6]
__print(__row(eye, 2));     // [7, 8, 9]

__print(__col(eye, 0));     // [1, 4, 7]
__print(__col(eye, 1));     // [2, 5, 8]
__print(__col(eye, 2));     // [3, 6, 9]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/8.1.1/math.js"></script>
```

Turns out that they are already implemented, but you still need to flatten the result.

```js
const __print = (x) => console.log(JSON.stringify(x));

let eye = math.matrix([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]);

const __row = (m, r) =>
  math.flatten(math.row(m, r).valueOf());
  
const __col = (m, c) =>
  math.flatten(math.column(m, c).valueOf());
  
const __cell = (m, r, c) =>
  math.subset(m, math.index(r, c));

__print(__cell(eye, 0, 0)); // 1

__print(__row(eye, 0));     // [1, 2, 3]
__print(__row(eye, 1));     // [4, 5, 6]
__print(__row(eye, 2));     // [7, 8, 9]

__print(__col(eye, 0));     // [1, 4, 7]
__print(__col(eye, 1));     // [2, 5, 8]
__print(__col(eye, 2));     // [3, 6, 9]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/8.1.1/math.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to combine both `subset` and `index` to get the value at the index.

Source: [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html#getting-or-replacing-subsets)

```
math.subset(eye, math.index(0, 0)) // 1
math.subset(eye, math.index(0, 1)) // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reach content of eye  as if eye is 2 dimensional js array, which is definitely not true. math.matrix returns some object, the best way to investigate it's structure is console.log(eye) (in Chrome or other modern browser). Or/and read docs about it methods